# Why I am getting MissingResourceException locale en_US when I have defined default locale as es_ES?

Tags: jsf-2, resources, bundle

I have defined as default locale message bundle as es_ES, but when I use the en_US configuration I get MissingResourceException.

Why is it not getting the default es_ES resource?

**Packages**

[image]

**faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>es_ES</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>es_ES</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>ca_ES</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<message-bundle>es.roscam.i18n.messages</message-bundle>
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>es.roscam.i18n.messages</base-name>
    <var>msgs</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

**Error description**

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name es.roscam.i18n.messages, locale en_US
    ... 
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name es.roscam.i18n.messages, locale en_US
```

Comment: Putting 'default-locale jsf' in google resulted in the duplicate, so try  https://www.google.com/search?q=default-locale+jsf

Comment: I did many searches without luch but that, sorry!

Comment: So it is 'fixed' by the duplicate?

Comment: I'm still testing, but it looks well...